# A reference on a result by Steve Schanuel

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, smooth-manifolds, topos-theory, synthetic-differential

In the Author Commentary section of the [TAC](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/15/tr15.pdf) reprint of the paper of 1968 [Diagonal arguments and cartesian closed categories.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0080769), Bill Lawvere wrote:

‘Nilpotent infinitesimals fall far short of even one-dimensionality, but if taken to be non-commutative, are already adequate for holomorphic functions, as was strikingly shown by Steve Schanuel (1982).’

What could be actually the result Bill Lawvere would have in mind writing this and what would be the correct reference for that result?

Comment: I think the paper must be "Continuous extrapolation to triangular matrices characterizes smooth functions" JPAA (1982).

Comment: Link: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82721817.pdf, and doi link https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(82)90058-5, for the paper in Dave Benson's comment